# How do you test a slider using detox?

Tags: react-native, detox

In my react-native application, I have a slider which sets a value. How the slider works is you click and drag the slider to set the value. My question is how do you test this using the actioners of detox ?

Comment: can i see the your code?

Comment: Not possible right now. Once we finish our major rewrite, we may expose this API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use swipe() action of detox.